# How to figure out what fonts are supported on android?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, languages, 6.0-marshmallow

My mother tongue is called [Manipuri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meithei_language) and we have a script called [Meetei/Meitei Mayek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meithei_script).

I am trying to create a input keyboard for the script. Up till Android 5, the OS doesn't seem to support the script. However, on Android M, when I visit a site with the script, it displays properly (at least on Chrome for Android). I thought perhaps the OS now supports the script.

I then tried to create a keyboard mapped to the unicode for the characters but it ended up displaying boxes.

How can I figure out whether the script is natively supported on the OS?

[Updated: Figured out the script is supported because I can see proper characters now. I had chosen the wrong emulator and that was the reason why I saw the boxes. However I think this must not be the optimal way to check support]

Comment: Can you use Bengali keyboard for your tongue?

Comment: We use to use Bengali script in the past but the original script is becoming more popular in the recent past.

Comment: There is already a keyboard for your language in play store. Have you tried [this Meetei Mayek Keyboard plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=klye.plugin.mm)

Comment: Yes I've tried this. I want to take advantage of the native support. This app must've bundled the font with the app.

Comment: @ptamzz in case you wonder about my edit of the title: "script" is a bit ambiguous here and might be confused with "development issues".

Comment: This may either be an issue of 1. the encoding not supporting these characters or 2. the font not having actual representations stored for these characters. It doesn't suffice to have proper Unicode with the script in it, because Unicode does not store the picture of the characters, but only says what byte sequence should result in.